# Adding data inside unordered_map inside a class

Tags: c++, class, struct, unordered-map

I have a class Citydata, defined in .hh file

```
struct City_details {
   string name;
   int taxrate;
};

class Citydata {
public:
   bool add_data(string id, string name, int taxrate)
   //other member functions...
private:
   unordered_map<id, City_details> info_map;
```

I have trouble implementing the add_data function in .cc file. Here is my try.

```
bool Citydata::add_data(string id, string name, int taxes) {
   if ( info_map.find(id) == info_map.end()) {
       City_details dataload;
       dataload.name = name;
       dataload.taxrate = taxes;
       info_map[id] = dataload;
       return true;
   }
   else return false;
}
```

When I test this, I cannot see any data added the way I wanted. Instead I see one completely empty entry (default empty values), and one entry with right id (the key) but no data added to the parameters. Each time I call add_data, it creates similar pair of one completely empty key-data member, then one with right id and otherwise empty data.

The original program is much longer than this, so problem might persist there too, but I wonder if my approach is flawed by design.

Comment: The code you showed looks correct.

Comment: First, you should replace `unordered_map<id, City_details> info_map;` with `unordered_map<std::string, City_details> info_map;`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications that makes your program work.

**First** you should replace `unordered_map<id, City_details> info_map;` with `unordered_map<std::string, City_details> info_map;`

**Second** you had a missing semicolon `;` for you `add_data` member function declaration inside the class which you might have missed while copy pasting the code here on Stackoverflow.

**Third** i have avoided the use of `using namespace std;`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"
int main()
{
  
   Citydata c1;
    c1.add_data("id1","Georgia", 34);
    c1.add_data("id2", "California", 32);
    c1.add_data("id3","Texas", 23);
    //lets print out the element of info_map
    for(auto &it:c1.info_map)
        std::cout << it.first <<" "<<it.second.name<<" "<<it.second.taxrate<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**file.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
struct City_details {
   std::string name;
   int taxrate;
};

class Citydata {
public:
   bool add_data(std::string id, std::string name, int taxrate);
   //other member functions...
//private:
   std::unordered_map<std::string, City_details> info_map;//the first tempate argument should be int and not id
};
```

**file.cpp**

```
#include "file.h"
bool Citydata::add_data(std::string id, std::string name, int taxes) {
   if ( info_map.find(id) == info_map.end()) {
       City_details dataload;
       dataload.name = name;
       dataload.taxrate = taxes;
       info_map[id] = dataload;
       return true;
   }
   else return false;
}
```